# Delete all rows with specific text and range

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code so far. Problem is that it deletes the first row. I want to exclude first row (the header). Because the rows i was deleting was duplicate headers

[Code] Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

```
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


With ActiveSheet.Select


    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView


    .DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(2).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -2


        With .Cells(Lrow, "D")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If .Value = "Service Tower" Then .EntireRow.Delete

            End If

        End With

    Next Lrow

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With [code]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.UsedRange.Cells(2)
```

is the second cell on the first row of the UsedRange.  Cells are counted left-to-right then top-to-bottom (ie. "row-major" not "column-major")

You want

```
Firstrow = .UsedRange.Rows(2).Row
```